# Wpf DataBinding to a friend property

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net

I am currently writing a class library which will be consumed by a customer of me. In addition I am writing a small wpf-gui for testing purposes. This gui needs to see a few more information than the customer. So I declared a few property as protected friend (VB) / protected internal (C#) and additional set the InternalsVisibleTo-Attribute of my library to the gui of me.

While accessing the friend properties from code behind works well, the wpf-databinding to those failed.

Is there any solution to this issue?

Comment: No, data binding only works with public properties.

Comment: Haven't tried, but you could perhaps declare an internal static reference to an info object (with public properties) that is accessed via `Source="{x:Static YourClass.Info}"`.

Comment: You could translate the data to a viewmodel. In the class library.  It seems odd that you've made a class library and data you then want to at least display can only be used in that class library. You put it in a box, locked the box. Then you have problems getting at it. Maybe these should just be public properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data binding only works with `public` properties.

In you case, you can use `public` property with the `protected internal set` like this:

```
public string MyProperty { get; protected internal set; }
```

This ensures that property can be read by anyone BUT cannot be modified from the outside of the class/subclass and assembly.

Other alternative to this is to expose separate public, get-only property that takes the value from your protected-internal property like this:

```
public string MyProperty => MyProtectedInternalProperty;
```

Comment: I first tried the second one with the extra property, which doesn't worked for me because the MyProtectedInternalProperty is also a bound property and not  set at the time the property is called. So I have chossen the other solution with different access modifiers for  get and set, which is OK for me

Answer (score 0):

The from model to view binding is not proper way.
I recommend to make a ViewModel in order to bind from ViewModel to View.
The model is just model